# Make activity wait for specific time period

Tags: android, android-activity

I have following code snippet in my application activity.

If user is landing on activity for the first time then only thing that will happen is changing the boolean variable `shouldSleep` to `true`.

Thereafter, `else` part will be executed which contains **generation of `notification` at every 60 seconds**.

But the main problem is if I execute this code, the activity ***NEVER*** gets displayed as it keeps looping in else part and hence go on sleeping.

What I want is remaining application should run normally while every 60 seconds, `else` part of this method should be executed.
I guess it has got something to do with `AsyncTask` but I don't have much idea about it.

Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
boolean shouldSleep=false;
private void ShowNotification() 
{
    //DO SOME TASK

    if (shouldSleep) 
    {
        Thread.sleep(60000);
        //DO SOME TASK
    } 

    else
   {
        shouldSleep = true;
   }

        /** Calling the method recursively so that it always runs. */
        ShowNotification();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a Timer object :

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //This code is run all 60seconds
        myBooleanVar = true;
        //If you want to operate UI modifications, you must run ui stuff on UiThread.
        Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Activity.this.changeUiStuff();
            }
        });
    }
}, 60000);
```

Comment: should I put my whole method withing run() of your code snippet? Of course without using `Thread.sleep(60000);`.

Comment: You should put the working code in the run method. If i understand correctly, it's the "//DO SOME TASK" thing you'll have to put in TimerTask->run().
The method Runnable->run() should execute UI stuff, like setting text in a label.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). Instead of a thread approach, you could run your task every 60s:

```
new Timer().schedule(task, delay, period);
```

with period = 60*1000